# Delete single item from Firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I need to **delete a user from the group chat** once he clicks the exit group button. The above picture is how my database looks like

Suppose I want to delete the user with `user_id: 15213`

Here's my code:

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference groupMemberRef = database.getReference().child("group_users/"+chatGroup.group_id+"/"+userId);

    groupMemberRef.removeValue();
```

While the code is technically correct, the entry isn't getting removed from the database.

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried deleting a node the way you implemented. But I did as below:

```
DatabaseReference groupMemberRef = database.getReference().child("group_users/"+chatGroup.group_id+"/"+userId);
groupMemberRef.setValue(null);
```

See if it works..

Comment: I tried this but it still doesnt work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("group_users/" + chatGroup.group_id).orderByChild("user_id").equalsTo(15213);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: What is the error you get now? In your code, you forgot a `child`. Even `1` is a node, even is a single digit.

Comment: 1 is being accounted for in the chatGroup.group_id thats what 1 is and that is followed by the userID...No error though

Comment: I just edited my post. Please try again the code. There were 2 errors in your code. The missing child and the wrong field key. You need `user_id` in stead of `userId`.

Comment: Does it work with this changes? The `child("1")` added and `user_id` in stead of `userId`?

Comment: ok i think you are confused..... chatGroup.group_id gives 1 and after that, I need to go down and delete the user with user_id:15213

Comment: I understand now. Please see my edited answer. The error is because you  did not put in your `reference` that unique id generated by the `push` method. If you use something like this: `database.getReference().child("group_users").child(chatGroup.group_id).child(KHmHncpTX......).child(user_id).removeValue();` it will work for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141376/discussion-between-prateek-phoenix-and-alex-m).